# mojo configuration not initialized before execute in custom maven plugin

Tags: maven, initialization, nullpointerexception, execute, mojo

Given that I have the following custom mojo...

```
/**
 * @goal portal-test
 */
public class PortalTestMojo extends AbstractMojo {


    /*
     * @parameter
     * @required
     */
    private String baseUrl;

    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {
        getLog().info("" + baseUrl.isEmpty());
    }

}
```

...when I run using mvn test on the following pom...

```
 25   <build>
 26     <plugins>
 27       <plugin>
 28         <groupId>com.lgi.plugins</groupId>
 29         <artifactId>maven-plugin-facade</artifactId>
 30         <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 31         <executions>
 32           <execution>
 33             <id>testing-mojo</id>
 34             <phase>test</phase>
 35             <goals>
 36               <goal>portal-test</goal>
 37             </goals>
 38           </execution>
 39         </executions>
 40         <configuration>
 41             <baseUrl>TEST</baseUrl>
 42           
 45         </configuration>
 46       </plugin>
 47     </plugins>
 48   </build>
```

...I get a null pointer exception on baseUrl

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.lgi.day:maven-plugin-facade:1.0-SNAPSHOT:portal-test (testing-mojo) on project testPom: Execution testing-mojo of goal com.lgi.day:maven-plugin-facade:1.0-SNAPSHOT:portal-test failed. NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.lgi.day:maven-plugin-facade:1.0-SNAPSHOT:portal-test (testing-mojo) on project testPom: Execution testing-mojo of goal com.lgi.day:maven-plugin-facade:1.0-SNAPSHOT:portal-test failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:225)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution testing-mojo of goal com.lgi.day:maven-plugin-facade:1.0-SNAPSHOT:portal-test failed.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.lgi.day.PortalTestMojo.execute(PortalTestMojo.java:52)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
```

Can any one tell me why my maven configuration parameters are not initialized before execute (when they are clearly defined int the pom)  ??????

The pom file above is used in an integration test for the plugin which passes. Here is the code:

```
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.AbstractMojoTestCase;
import com.lgi.day.PortalTestMojo;

public class MojoVaribaleAssignmentTest extends AbstractMojoTestCase {

    private final String TEST = "TEST";

    public void testMojoGoal() throws Exception {
        File testPom = new File(getBasedir(), "src/test/resources/testPom.xml");

        PortalTestMojo mojo = (PortalTestMojo) lookupMojo("portal-test",
                testPom);

        assertEquals(TEST, mojo.getBaseUrl());
        assertEquals(TEST, mojo.getPortalPath());
        assertEquals(TEST, mojo.getUserName());
        assertEquals(TEST, mojo.getPassword());
    }

}
```

Here is the pom file for the plugin itself:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.lgi.day</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-plugin-facade</artifactId>
  <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>maven-plugin-facade Maven Mojo</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lgi.day</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-portal-tests-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-testing-harness</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-beta-1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-tools</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I am using maven version 3.0.3

Comment: Just to clear add a default-value for your parameter and recheck. To be sure it's not simply a typo etc. Furthermore it would help if you can post your pom.xml (which Maven version do you use?) Do you have any integration tests ? Or did you manually installed the plugin for testing purposes into your local repository?

Comment: (Sorry not enough room in the comments section, please see the question section itself, where I have added the resources you requested)

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved!!!

I typed in mvn help:effective pom and noticed that the maven-plugin-plugin version was 2.7

I then looked at the generated plugin descriptor @target/classes/META-INF/maven/plugin.xml and noticed that the parameters element was empty ()

In other words the maven-plugin-plugin descriptor goal for version 2.7 does not interpret the old legacy annotations that appear in comments.

I upgraded my pom to use a more recent version of maven-plugin-plugin and added the maven-plugin-annotations as a dependency. The necessary changes are outlined here:

http://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-plugin/examples/using-annotations.html

I then annotated the mojo...

```
@Mojo(name = "portal-test")
public class PortalTestMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    @Parameter(required = true)
    private String baseUrl;
```

...etc

The parameters element was then populated in the plugin descriptor